# Bad Request binding objects in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, binding

We are trying to do a three level binding:

> GrandFather -> (has many) Parent -> (has many) Child

Our GrandFather and parents are saved in database then they have id's autogenerated. But our Child's are new in some cases and they haven't id values.

When we send this information by ajax to our server (Weblogic), we are doing a binding to the data using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blablabla/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateProducts(@ModelAttribute GrandFather grandpa, BindingResult result, Model model) {

...
}
```

The result is that you see a Bad Request error in your browser (using Firebug). We only see that the child haven't ids, the others values are perfect. You can't see any in server side, any code of your method is executed.

That wouldn't be a problem, but it's. Any ideas about what's happen?

Thanks.

Note. We are using Spring framework; Spring MVC; Weblogic server and other controllers and bindings are working.

**Update**:

The html code used:

```
<c:forEach items="${question.answers}" var="answer" varStatus="statusAnswer"> 
... 
<c:forEach items="${answer.ratings}" var="rating" varStatus="statusRating"> 
... 
<input type="hidden" name="questions[${statusQuestion.index}].id" value="${question.id}"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="questions[${statusQuestion.index}].respuestas[${statusQuestion.index}].ratings[${statusRating.index}].id" value="${valoracion.id}" /> 
... 
</c:forEach> 
... 
</c:forEach>
```

The how to send it's difficult to paste here have a lot of javascript to fill some values of the objects.

Comment: Can you post the html code you use to call the controller? Do you have any initBinder with a @RequestParam in the controller?

Comment: I've added the html code that we use. And no, we are not using any initBinder in our Controller.

Comment: @jenaiz we can't see the html code.

Comment: sorry. I haven't scaped html code :( .

Comment: @jenaiz next time: don't escape anything. select the code and click the formatter icon (the one with the {})

Comment: in the form tag have you set as method POST?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have solution about this problem.
If you are sending data using the ajax then please do not use model attribute.
Get your parameter using request object in controller.

write code like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blablabla/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateProducts(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

...
}
```